# Advanced R function call

Tags: r, function

all, this may sound dummy, but I need to understand some legacy R code while I know nothing of it.  I hope someone could give me some hint on what's going on below:

```
g = if (calc.tstat){
function(...) FUN(...)} else 
{function(...) FUN(..1)}
```

These 3 lines are part of a function (famamacb) called by below:

```
temp <- famamacb(include = include, 
               function(coef) list(tseries.tstat = apply(coef,2, cumtstat, na.rm = T, i = 
match(rownames(coef), rownames(time.weight)))))
```

My understanding is FUN(...) refers to the function(coef), which generates a list.  Could someone correct me if I'm wrong?  But what does FUN(..1) do then?

Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`..1` refers to the *first* element from the variable number of arguments supplied through the ellipsis argument (see also `help("...")` for more information).

Here is a minimal example, showing how `..2` refers to the *second* element from the arguments supplied through `...`.

```r
f <- function (x, ...) return(c(x, list(..2)))

f("zero", "one", "two")
#[[1]]
#[1] "zero"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "two"
```

Comment: Hi, Maurits, thanks much for your kind reply, greatly appreciated! Best wishes